# jQuery function still firing after $(window).resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a search form that I wish to be always visible on desktop sizes (992px+) and hidden on mobile with a toggle button. *Crucially, I also want the form to fold away after a user submits the search form.*

All of the functionality described above works as intended except when you resize the browser window from less than 992px to above 992px, the submit button *still* hides the search form—this shouldn’t happen. Everything works fine without resize.

This can be replicated in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n68zdvjc/1/).

Here’s my code:

**Hide search form after submit**

```
// Close search form on mobile when clicking search input
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);

  function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();

    if (windowsize < 992) {
      $('#search-form input').unbind().click(function() {
        $('#search-form').slideToggle(250).removeClass('open');
        $('a.search-toggle').removeClass('open');
      });
    }
  }
  // Execute on load
  checkWidth();
  // Bind event listener
  $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

**Form toggle button (hidden at desktop sizes):**

```
// Hide/show search form on mobile 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.search-toggle').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('#search-form').slideToggle(250, function() {
      $('#search-form').toggleClass('open', $(this).is(':visible'));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: should it be $(window).resize(checkWidth());

Comment: Why are you even using JS to check the browser size? This should be achieved only by using media queries...

Comment: Yep Media queries would be a easier solution.

Comment: Short answer: Label+Checkbox and use the sibling selector in CSS for a CSS only solution. Can do an answer for that if you want.

Comment: I would nearly always use media queries although perhaps I’m missing something as I didn’t think you could hide something in CSS after someone clicks a submit button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are

```js
// Hide/show search form on mobile 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.search-toggle').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('#search-form').slideToggle(250, function() {
      $('#search-form').toggleClass('open', $(this).is(':visible'));
    });
  });
});

// Close search form on mobile when clicking search input
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $window = $(window);
  var inMobileMode = false;
  var inDesktopMode = false;

  function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();

    if (windowsize < 992 && !inMobileMode) {
      $('#search-form input').click(function() {
        $('#search-form').slideToggle(250).removeClass('open');
        $('a.search-toggle').removeClass('open');
      });
      inMobileMode = true;
      inDesktopMode = false;
      
    } else if(windowsize >= 992 && !inDesktopMode) {
     $('#search-form input').off('click');
      $('#search-form').slideDown(250).addClass('open');
       inDesktopMode = true;
        inMobileMode = false;
    }
  }
  // Execute on load
  checkWidth();
  // Bind event listener
  $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
}

#search-form{
  padding: 30px;
  background: #eee;
}

@media ( min-width: 992px ){
  a.search-toggle{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="search-toggle">Toggle search form</a>

<div id="search-form">
  <input type="Submit" value="Search">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any script running for implementing the behavior you like to achieve.

Here's a CSS only solution:

```css
label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#search-form {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: none;
  /* hide search form by default */
}


/* This does the whole magic */

input:checked+#search-form {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="searchToggle">
  Toggle search
</label>
<input id="searchToggle" type="checkbox">
<div id="search-form">
  <input type="Submit" value="Search">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice—although this appears to hide the form when you click the form, not the submit button?

Comment: @Stuart Oh sorry, I didn't thought of that... What a fail xD I've updated my example to fix this bug!